# Pointer confusion

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, pointers

I am confused about one pointer situation explained below;

In class A

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *words;
```

In class B

```
 @property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *words;

 //creating a pointer to words from classB
 self.words = [classB words];
```

Now if I add new word to words array in Class A, why don't I see that word in words array in class B? I thought my words array in Class B is a pointer to Class A words?

Comment: Both are belong to different class. then how can it possible?

Comment: @Cyprian Is `words` property in `classB` is instantiated by the time you do the assignment?

Comment: It should work. There’s something else in your code that’s causing the arrays to be different.

Comment: @Deepak yes it is instantiated before.

Comment: @Bavarious, you are right it should work, my error has to be somewhere else.

Comment: The above code appears to assign classB words to itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some of you guys here said it should work and it is. I had some errors in my code. But wanted to give a little example code to prove that this is how it should be:

```
#import "PointersAppDelegate.h"

#import "PointersViewController.h"

#import "ClassA.h"
#import "ClassB.h"

@implementation PointersAppDelegate

@synthesize window=_window;

@synthesize viewController=_viewController;

@synthesize classA, classB;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    classA = [[ClassA alloc] init];
    classB = [[ClassB alloc] init];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    //Add new word to words in classA
    [[classA words] addObject:@"two"];

    //Print words in classB
    [classB print];

    return YES;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_window release];
    [_viewController release];

    [classA release];
    [classB release];

    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

//Class A

```
// ClassA.h

@interface ClassA : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray *words;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *words;

@end


// ClassA.m

#import "ClassA.h"

@implementation ClassA

@synthesize words;


- (id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        words = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"one", nil];
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [words release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

ClassB

```
// ClassB.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface ClassB : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray *words;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *words;

-(void)print;

@end


// ClassB.m
#import "ClassB.h"
#import "PointersAppDelegate.h"

@implementation ClassB

@synthesize words;

- (id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.words = [[(PointersAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] classA] words];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)print{
    for(int i=0;i<[words count];i++)
        NSLog(@"%@", [words objectAtIndex:i]);
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [words release];

    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

The result is:

```
2011-07-04 12:38:33.759 Pointers[20059:707] one
2011-07-04 12:38:33.767 Pointers[20059:707] two
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically the changes should reflect in both arrays, until you change the *reference* of any of the two objects some where in your code.

```
//creating a pointer to words from classB
self.words = [classB words];
```

And some where in your *Class A* or *Class B*,

```
self.words = someOtherArray;
```

This will make the *words* array of both the classes to point different objects.

Comment: I thought that retain is just declaring the ownership of an object and not creating a copy of it.

Comment: @Cyprian, Yes. Sorry. You are right. Make sure you haven't assigned any other reference to any of those two words array somewhere else. – EmptyStack

Comment: actually as Bavarious said, the idea is correct, I had some errors in my code.

Comment: @Cyprian, Yes. That is what I too said ;-)

Answer (score 1):

is it the code you try to run ?
If yes, it seems there is a mystake in your class B code since *words* in class B is the same as [classB words]. (in class B : self.words = [classB words]).
Maybe an instruction like : self.words = [**classA** words].... should resolve your problem (assuming classA is an object of class A).